# Перехват http запросов

Tags: javascript, html

есть такая задача,что с определенного времени (события) нужно перехватывать переходы по страницам,ну т.е какие вкладки пользователь открывал ,и все это записывать в какой-то объект. Подскажите как такое можно реализовать средствами js ,может способ какой есть или метод)
И желательно,чтобы этот способ работал в ie10+

Comment: в localStorage можно писать. про "перехват" может не совсем понял, можно же просто при загрузке страницы ставить ее в массив со всеми урлами

Comment: Ну вот смотрите,пользователь кликает на кнопку,с этого момента начинается перехват,т.е он начинает лазить по сайту,а все сетевые логи(урлы) записываются ко мне в какой-то объект,вот так примерно

Comment: @Jarvis Прослеживание совсем всех действий человека в браузере не очень хорошая идея, получается что Вы за ним следите, или хуже того, просматриваете какие данные на каких сайтах он ввел. Если же Вам нужно просто отследить его действия после нажатия на кнопку, то Вы можете повесить событие на нажатие кнопки и отмечать, что кнопка была нажата. Если это тестирующая система, то лучшим вариантом, на мой взгляд, будет запрет выхода из окна(надо отдельно гуглить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Накидал примерное решение:

```
let getUrlHistory = function(storageKey){
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey));
};


let buffPushState = (function(){
   return history.pushState.bind(history);
})();

history.pushState = function(data, title, url = null){
    let storageKey = 'url_stack';
    if (!localStorage.getItem(storageKey)){
         localStorage.setItem(storageKey, '[]');
    }
    let url_stack = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey));

    url_stack.push({
        data : data,
        title: title,
        url : url
    });
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(url_stack));
    console.log('push:', url);
    return buffPushState(data, title, url);
};
```

суть в чем, переопределяешь стандартный метод history.pushState
предварительно запоминаем его, потом вместо history.pushState указываем нашу функцию, в которой делаем наши отслеживания, и в конце вызываем наш исходный pushState. Соответственно не ломаем нормальный функционал и добавляем туда наш.
Браузеры при переходах вызывают данную функцию. Данный храний в localStorage.

Данный код вызови как можно выше. По идее должно работать